# Convert a time stamp in javascript which is having a time period (+0800) to be added in it's end

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I wanted to convert a timestamp which i am getting as below format

> "2019-08-31T00:00:00+0800"

when i am converting into date using javascript it is giving me

> Fri, 30 Aug 2019 16:00:00 GMT

But the desired date is

> 31 Aug 2019

I have noticed that there is +0800 at the end of the timestamp, if i add that time to the GMT time, it is giving me the desired result.
Is there any method or a date function to convert it. or do we have any angular pipes to convert it into the desired date ?

 which format of date is it actually ?

can refer to this link for GMT +8 offset - https://greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/gmt-plus-8/

Answer (score 0):

For dates and time it is easier to work with Moment, so you can use the format function:

[Moment Format](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/)

Or use the toLocaleDateString function:

[toLocaleDateString Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

So you can do this:

```
var options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('en-EN', options));
```

Will give you this:

> "December 20, 2012"

You can play with the options to get the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use date-fns which is more modular. https://date-fns.org/. You can import only the parts of date-fns that you use. Moment is big

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It is no function, it's a crude way. You can check it out if it works for you. Try with all the different cases to verify.

```js
var this_date = '2019-08-31T00:00:00+0800'
var date = new Date(this_date).toDateString()
var date_list = date.split(' ');
date = [ date_list[2], date_list[1], date_list[3] ].join(' ')
console.log(typeof date);
console.log(date)
```

```js
var this_date = '2019-08-31T00:00:00+0800'
var date = new Date(this_date)
console.log(date.toString())
```

You can as well take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript), an older stackoverflow post.
You can use it as a function if you like it. If you are looking for something else, Please give the functions you are using for conversion and as well try to find the 'typeof' variable.